# The type or namespace name "" cannot be found

Tags: c#, winforms

When trying to refer to the class "Deck" in the class "Hands" i am receiving the error message that the namespace cant be found.

I also tried to just use another name of one of my classes called "Random Number" and this worked so I am not sure on my error.

```cs
public class Deck 
{
    public List<Card> Cards { set; get; }//The List is the list of cards in the deck

    public Deck() //creates the pack of cards
    {
        Cards = new List<Card>();
        revealdeck();
    }

    public void revealdeck()
    {
        Cards.Clear();
        int card_number = 1;
        for (int E = 1; E < 5; E++)  // 4 different suits
        {
            for (int F = 1; F < 14; F++) // 13 different numbers in the cards 13x4 = 52
            {
                Card cardnow = new Card(); //creates the new card
                cardnow.cardnum = card_number;
                if (E == 1)
                    cardnow.cardsuit = "spades";
                if (E == 2)
                    cardnow.cardsuit = "clubs";
                if (E == 3)
                    cardnow.cardsuit = "hearts";
                if (E == 4)
                    cardnow.cardsuit = "diamonds";
                cardnow.cardvalue = F;

                Cards.Add(cardnow);
                card_number = cardnumber++;
            }
        }
    }

    public Card SearchingCards(int card_number)
    {
        foreach (Card w_card in Cards)
        {
            if (w_card.cardnum != card_number)
            {
                return null;
            }
            else
            {
                return w_card;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
{
    public class Hand
    {
        public List<Card> Cards { set; get; }
        public int AmtOFCards { set; get; }
        public int Chips{ set; get; }
        public string Winner { set; get;}

        public Hand(int numOFcards)
        {
            AmtOFCards = numOFcards; //Cards in users hand
            Cards = new List<Card>(); // this list is to hold the cards
            Card card0 = new Card(); //Removes value
            for (int y = 0; y < numOFcards; y++)
            {
                Cards.Add(card0); // Adds card with no value to list
            }

        }

        public void Cardadd(***Deck*** thisdeck, int cards_in_a_hand) // This is where I am getting the error.
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it possible that there is a Namespace with the same name as a class? or are you missing a `using` statement at the top of the file containing the class `card`?

Comment: The namespaces seem to be relevant for your question. So please show the namespaces. The usings might be relevant too.

Comment: You have braces outside of `public class Hand`. Are those for a namespace? Or are they just sitting there? What else is in the file?

Comment: If you define Class "Hand" in another file you should add "Deck" namespace by "using"  keyword. like "using Models.MyClasses"

Comment: You've got another problem with your `SearchingCards` method - If the card isn't the first one in the deck, the method returns `null`. Probably should remove that from the loop and add it at the end, so that if, after iterating over all the cards, no match is found, *then* return `null`

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/74746301/5438626 help answer your question? It "deals" with class visibility for a card game. There's also a minimal sample attached to it that you can clone and play around with.